# Remove hyperref link form citation within section

Tags: hyperref, natbib, links

Using Natbib and Hyperref i want to use a citation within a section title.

I want to use a citation in a section name. I would like to have the citation link within the section title. However I do not want the link to appear within the TOC.

I started with the following:

```
\subsection{\citeauthor*{bibentry}}
```

Now I have links within the section title and the TOC.

I then tried:

```
\subsection[\begin{NoHyper}\citeauthor*{bibentry}\end{NoHyper}]{\citeauthor*{bibentry}}
```

But this didn't work, presumably due to the environment within the section definition.

I tried to create a command that would expand this first but was unsuccessful.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you just hard-code the citation callout string in the optional argument of `\section`, i.e., write `\section[Something about Smith]{Something about \citeauthor{bibentry}}`?